# Parsing RSS via RaptureXML

Tags: nsxmlparser, libxml2

How to work with tags `<itunes:summary>text</itunes:summary>`?

These following codes does not work:

```
episode.summary = [item child:@"summary" inNamespace:@"itunes"].text;
```

or

```
episode.summary = [item child:@"summary:itunes"].text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RaptureXML automatically deletes namespaces.

```
episode.summary = [item child:@"summary"].text;
```