# Parsing data for tag which has colon using RaptureXML in iOS

Tags: ios, xml

I have the xml structure xml like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <item>      
      <comments>http://www.rtl.fr/actu/politique/laurent-gerra-imitant-nicolas-sarkozy-il-faut-barrer-la-
      <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
    </item>  
  </channel>
</rss>
```

How can I get text in `<slash:comments>` tag.
I already try(Swift version):

```
elementItem.child("comments",inNamespace: "slash").
```

But it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730027/parsing-rss-via-rapturexml), RaptureXML deletes namespaces, so you can access your content via

```
elementItem.child("comments")
```